# iPad App Navigation with SlideView - change size of UIView?

Tags: ios, swift

i want to create a slide out menu which has a normal width of about 50 pixels, and if the user press the expand button i will also show the labels for the button.

Like in this example:

[image: Example Menu]

What is the correct way to create such a menu? I though about using 2 views and set the size of contentview to width-50pixels.

But i am unable to change the frame of my UIView in the ViewDidLoad function. (this is an example)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.frame = CGRect(x:50, y:0, width:974, height:768)

    sidebarIsOpen = false
}
```

And if the user click on the expand Button

```
@IBAction func expandButtonClicked(sender : AnyObject) {

    var x = self.sidebarIsOpen! ? 50 : 300
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x:x, y:0, width:300, height:768)
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.sidebarIsOpen = !(self.sidebarIsOpen!)
        })
}
```

If i click the button again, everything is fine. But on ViewDidLoad i am unable to move the contentview to right.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ill found already the solution by myself.

Created 2 views and animate the "contentview" on button click.

```
@IBOutlet weak var menuView: UIView!

@IBAction func toggleMenuButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var x = self.sidebarIsOpen! ? 50 : 200

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        self.contentView.frame = CGRect(x:x, y:0, width:974, height:768)
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.sidebarIsOpen = !(self.sidebarIsOpen!)
        })

}
```